# ggvis figure can't zoom in an embedded shiny app in shiny markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, ggvis, shiny

I have a shiny app embedded in a shiny markdown document. If I run the app lonely, the ggvis figure can zoom in and out like the following picture:
[image]

Pay attention to the small arrow in the rigth bottom.

But when I embed this app to shiny markdown document by using the following code:

`````
````{r, echo = FALSE}
    require(ggvis)
    require(knitr)
    require(shiny)
    shinyAppDir(
           system.file("../../../../Shiny/DataProcess/R", package="shiny"),
           options=list( width="100%",height=1000)
    )
````
`````

This app is correctly embedded. But the figure can't zoom. Like following:
[image]

The small arrow disappears.

I am new to shiny and shiny markdown document, I hope your help.

1. My rstudio version is Version 0.98.1103
2. R version is R x64 3.2.0

Note : Using ggvis directely in shiny markdown document, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

By default shiny graphs have `options(resizable=TRUE)`, which creates that small arrow in the right bottom. 
I suppose in a markdown document `resizable` is set to `FALSE` or suppressed by setting `height` by hand

Comment: I embedded the app by `shinyAppDir(
  "./app/total",
  options=list(
    resizable=TRUE
  )
)` It still doesn't work.